# Select fields from sub query , but I face field could not be bounded

Tags: sql-server

```
SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY c.FullName ASC) AS No#,    
    a.AcctBranchName, 
    c.FullName,
    c.BirthDate,
    c.Age,
    a.StartDate as 'Account Start Date',
    c.CustStartDate as 'Customer Start Date',
    c.CustomerNum,
    a.Currency,
    a.AccountNum,
    a.ProductType as 'Product Name',
    a.Balance as 'Balance KHR',
    a.BalanceUSDEquiv as 'Balance USA',
    aa.ClosedDate,

    CASE 
        WHEN (a.BalanceUSDEquiv*3 >= 200000) then '200,000'
        ELSE a.BalanceUSDEquiv*3 end as 'Sum Insure in USD',
    CASE 
        WHEN (a.BalanceUSDEquiv*3 > 200000) then 200000*(0.1/100)/12 
        ELSE a.BalanceUSDEquiv*3*(0.1/100)/12 end as 'Premium to be paid'

FROM         
     v_Account AS a 
LEFT join v_Customer AS c 
    ON c.CustomerID = a.CustomerID AND c.Businessdate = a.Businessdate

WHERE     
    a.AccountNum IN ( 
        SELECT  aa.AccountNum FROM v_Account AS aa WHERE   
         aa.Category = 'Deposit' AND aa.ProductCode IN ('6003', '6253') 
        AND aa.Businessdate='2018-12-06' AND aa.ClosedDate is not NULL
    )  
    AND a.Category = 'Deposit' 
    AND a.ProductCode IN ('6003', '6253')
    AND c.Businessdate='2018-12-05'
```

How can I select `aa.ClosedDate` from my sub query or any alternate solution which I can get the ClosedDate of `2018-12-06`.

**Example.** Account number: 123456 is closed at date 2018-12-06 (closed mean no balance) So in order to get the balance of this account number I need to look up this at 2018-12-05 (before 1 day this account is closed) ,then I can get the balance for my calculation purpose for example.

Comment: *How can I select aa.ClosedDate from my sub query.* In common your table aliased as `aa` contain more than 1 record (including taking into account the conditions) and so more than one `ClosedDate` field values. And no criteria to select one of them.

Comment: With subquery do you mean the subquery in WHERE? `WHERE a.AccountNum IN (..subquery..)`?

Comment: do you have any alternative solution , to get the ClosedDate.

Comment: @kn3l - for a given account number, can multiple rows come out of your subquery for that account number?

Comment: @ScottHodgin one account number CANNOT come out muliple rows , example:

Account number: 123456 is closed at date 2018-12-06 (closed mean no balance)
So in order to get the balance of this account number I need to look up this at 2018-12-05 (before 1 day this account is closed) ,then I can get the balance for my calculation purpose for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment to the question of whether multiple rows could come out of your subquery for a given account number, you indicated that was not possible.  If that's true, I don't see why you can't simply `LEFT JOIN` by account number against a derived result of your subquery.

Not tested, but basically like this:

```
SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY c.FullName ASC) AS No#,    
    a.AcctBranchName, 
    c.FullName,
    c.BirthDate,
    c.Age,
    a.StartDate as 'Account Start Date',
    c.CustStartDate as 'Customer Start Date',
    c.CustomerNum,
    a.Currency,
    a.AccountNum,
    a.ProductType as 'Product Name',
    a.Balance as 'Balance KHR',
    a.BalanceUSDEquiv as 'Balance USA',
    aa.ClosedDate,

    CASE 
        WHEN (a.BalanceUSDEquiv*3 >= 200000) then '200,000'
        ELSE a.BalanceUSDEquiv*3 end as 'Sum Insure in USD',
    CASE 
        WHEN (a.BalanceUSDEquiv*3 > 200000) then 200000*(0.1/100)/12 
        ELSE a.BalanceUSDEquiv*3*(0.1/100)/12 end as 'Premium to be paid'

FROM         
     v_Account AS a 
LEFT join v_Customer AS c 
    ON c.CustomerID = a.CustomerID AND c.Businessdate = a.Businessdate
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT AccountNum, ClosedDate FROM v_Account WHERE   
        Category = 'Deposit' AND ProductCode IN ('6003', '6253') 
    AND Businessdate='2018-12-06' AND ClosedDate is not NULL
) aa on aa.AccountNum = a.AccountNum
WHERE 
        aa.AccountNum = a.AccountNum
    AND a.Category = 'Deposit' 
    AND a.ProductCode IN ('6003', '6253')
    AND c.Businessdate='2018-12-05'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY c.FullName ASC) AS No#,    
    a.AcctBranchName, 
    c.FullName,
    c.BirthDate,
    c.Age,
    a.StartDate as 'Account Start Date',
    c.CustStartDate as 'Customer Start Date',
    c.CustomerNum,
    a.Currency,
    a.AccountNum,
    a.ProductType as 'Product Name',
    a.Balance as 'Balance KHR',
    a.BalanceUSDEquiv as 'Balance USA',
    c.ClosedDate,
    CASE 
        WHEN (a.BalanceUSDEquiv*3 >= 200000) then '200,000'
        ELSE a.BalanceUSDEquiv*3 end as 'Sum Insure in USD',
    CASE 
        WHEN (a.BalanceUSDEquiv*3 > 200000) then 200000*(0.1/100)/12 
        ELSE a.BalanceUSDEquiv*3*(0.1/100)/12 end as 'Premium to be paid'
FROM         

     v_Account AS a 
LEFT join v_Customer AS c 
    ON c.CustomerID = a.CustomerID AND c.Businessdate = a.Businessdate

WHERE     

    AND a.Category = 'Deposit' 
    AND a.ProductCode IN ('6003', '6253')
    AND (a.Businessdate='2018-12-05' OR a.Businessdate='2018-12-06' AND 
         a.ClosedDate is not NULL)
```

Comment: Hi Lihi and thanks for your answer - could you add some additional details? You haven't added why you think your solution is the answer.

Comment: If I understand right your goal is to select all the accounts that there Businessdate is  2018-12-05 doesn't matter if they were closed or not and accounts that there Businessdate is  2018-12-06 and are not closed. The condition in the where close last line gives it to you with no need of a subquery. If I'm mistaken and you're goal is diffrent please let me know

Comment: Thanks but this is not solution, what I want is in the same table v_Account  the closedDate only exist for 2018-12-06, but the balance only exist for 2018-12-05. SO I need to all the balance and ClosedDate together, this kind of self reference join , but I am not sure

Comment: what is the balance? you can write the last line in the where close - AND ((a.Businessdate='2018-12-05'  AND a.ClosedDate is NULL) OR (a.Businessdate='2018-12-06' AND  a.ClosedDate is not NULL)). that will select accounts from 5/12 that where closed and accounts from 6/12 that are not closed. Is that what you want?